# Child attributes updated with .first_or_initialize not saving - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `quote` which has many `shipping methods`. When I save the `quote`, the shipping method prices are not updated when I use `.first_or_initialize`. I have also tried setting `autosave: true` on my association like so:

quote.rb

```
has_many :shipping_methods, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
```

I have a callback which refreshes my shipping methods & their prices (quote.rb).

```
before_save :refresh_shipping_rates

def refresh_shipping_rates
  ShippingMethod.refresh_rates(self, admin = true)
end
```

My ShippingMethod.refresh_rates function (shipping_method.rb):

```
def refresh_rates(record, admin)
    #api call that returns a list of rates
    updated_rates.each do |i|
         rate = record.shipping_methods.where(name: i.name).first_or_initialize
         rate.price = i.price
    end
end
```

My quote is updated via a form submission to my `update` action.

```
def update
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote.update(parameters)

    if @quote.valid?

        flash[:notice] = []
        flash[:notice] << "Successfully Updated"
        render "update"
    else
        flash[:error] = []
        @quote.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            flash[:error] << message 
        end
        render "layouts/fail"
    end

end
```

I assume the `shipping_methods` should be updated simply because they are associated to the parent record that is being updated even though none of their attributes are submitted through the form.

Comment: Where do you save `shipping_methods` or `quote`?

Comment: Just updated my question with those details. @mrzasa

Comment: At no point to you call `save` so why would you anticipate that it would save? You could add `rate.save` in the each loop or change `rate.price = i.price` to `rate.update_attribute(:price, i.price)` if you don't mind skipping validation for this change

Comment: `update` executes the `before_save` callback @engineersmnky

Comment: Yes on `quote` which is ignorant of  anything `refresh_rates` is doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
 rate = record.shipping_methods.where(name: i.name).first_or_initialize
```

`shipping_method` is loaded from DB to a new object in memory that is not associated with `quote`. You should either:

1. update the objects that are loaded in `shipping_method` association (without calling any methods that fetches them from the DB), or
2. save `shipping methods` separately

I would advise to try 1).

Answer (score 0):

This method should be:

```
def refresh_rates(record, admin)
    #api call that returns a list of rates
    updated_rates.each do |i|
         rate = record.shipping_methods.where(name: i.name).first_or_initialize
         rate.price = i.price
    end
end
```

to:

```
def refresh_rates(record, admin)
    #api call that returns a list of rates
    updated_rates.each do |i|
         rate = record.shipping_methods.where(name: i.name).first_or_initialize
         rate.price = i.price
         rate.save
    end
end
```

OR:

```
def refresh_rates(record, admin)
    #api call that returns a list of rates
    updated_rates.each do |i|
         rate = record.shipping_methods.where(name: i.name).first_or_initialize(price: i.price)
    end
end
```